# Java- String: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: string, stringbuilder

I was implementing the little Java class to solve the string problem on Hackerrank:

*Given the string, find its non-reducible form, considering one valid operation is to delete any pair of adjacent letters with same value.*

Ex:

> "aabcc" would become either "aab" or "bcc" after 1 operation.

However, I just want to mention about the block of code surrounding this error. Although I was able to solve the problem quite fine, I'm tempted by others to improve the solution's time performance by using the better approach of **StringBuilder()**

But I haven't figured out why the behavior of **append()** in my *StringBuilder* class could lead to the memory overflow or any sort of more complicated misbehavior.

Here's the code:

```
 static String super_reduced_string(String s){
    StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder(); 
    for (int i = 1; i < s.length(); i++){
        if (s.charAt(i-1) == s.charAt(i)){
            /* waste so much memory leak!!! java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
            //s = res.append(s.substring(0, i-1)).append(s.substring(i+1)).toString(); 
            */
            s = s.substring(0, i-1) + s.substring(i+1);
            i = 0; 
        }
    }
    //then check if it's non-empty, print it out
    if (s.length() != 0){
        return s; 
    }
    return "Empty String"; 
}
```

The part where I commented out is the misbehavior mentioned above. Please kindly help me reason through this bug, and debug it! It shouldn't be that hard.

Answer (score 0):

Just clear string builder after assigning to s.

```
s = res.append(s.substring(0, i-1)).append(s.substring(i+1)).toString(); 
res.setLength(0);
```